# A question about finding a system of invariants for a subgroup $H$ of the symmetric group $S_n$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, invariant-theory, symmetric-polynomials

If $H = S_n$ then then the  [*fundamental symmetric polynomials*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) allow to write any $S_n$-invariant polynomial $f$ as a polynomial expression of these elementary symmetric functions. In other words, $\mathbb{C}[x_1, \dots ,x_n]^{S_n} = \mathbb{C}[e_1, \dots ,e_n]$.

Now, given $H \le S_n$ a subgroup of the symmetric group, is there a general way to compute a system of invariants for  $\mathbb{C}[x_1, \dots , x_n]^H$ ?

EDIT:

A brute-force approach to find invariants for $\mathbb{C}[x_1, \dots,x_n]^H$ might be the Reynolds Operator?

It is defined as:

$$R : \mathbb{R}[x_1, \dots, x_n] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}[x_1, \dots, x_n]^H$$

$R(f):= \frac{1}{|H|}\sum_{g \in H}f(g \cdot \textbf{x})$.

So just for simplicity consider $\mathbb{Z}_3 \le S_3$ and we define a group action

\begin{align}
\mathbb{Z}_3 \times V &\rightarrow V\\
(g, \textbf{x}) &\mapsto g \cdot \textbf{x} := (x_1+g, \dots, x_n +g)
\end{align}

where $V$ is a real vector space of dimension $d$.

So for example if $d=2$ and we have $f(x,y)=x+y$ then the $\mathbb{Z}_3$ invariant version of $f$ might be

$$f_{inv}(x,y)= f(x,y)+f(x+1,y+1)+f(x+2,y+2) = 3x+3y$$

Is this correct?

Comment: What does $x_1+g$ mean? $x_1$ is a real number and $g\in\mathbb{Z}_3$, so it makes no sense to add them. The action you want is $(g,\boldsymbol{x})\mapsto (x_{g(1)},x_{g(2)},x_{g(3)})$, where we are regarding $g$ as a permutation of $1,2,3$.

Comment: Is the dimension of the vector space dependent on the number of the elements we have in the group? So it seems that here you have chosen a vector of dimension $3$ to define the action of $\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "compute. The ring $R$ of invariants is spanned as a vector space by symmetrized monomials $\sum_{h\in H} h\cdot m$, where $m$ is a monomial.
$R$ is generated as a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra by those symmetrized monomials of degree at most $h$. However, there is no nice description of a minimal generating set or the relations (syzygies) among these generators, etc. Various algebra packages can make these computations for reasonably small groups. Some additional information is [here](https://math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/38.pdf). See Theorem 1.2 in particular. This paper deals with more general group actions than $H\leq S_n$, but this extra condition does not affect the difficulty in finding a minimal set of generators.

Comment: Thanks for the paper reference, it seems pretty interesting. I have also edited my question with additional details and considerations.